# Fundamental system of solutions to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show how to determine the fundamental system of solutions of equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$ if one non-trivial solution of that equation is given.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u$ be the given solution, and let's look for a linearly independent solution $v$. If these solutions are linearly independent, the Wronskian
$$W = v'u-u'v$$
is nonzero. We have another equation for the Wronskian,
$$ W' = -pW. $$
We can solve this ($W = Ae^{-\int p(x) \, dx}$), and then determine $v$ by treating $v'u-u'v = W$ as a first-order equation for $v$ (the left-hand side is the derivative of $u^2\left( \frac{v}{u} \right)'$, to start you off).